# Printing octal literal in printf

Tags: c, octal

What is the proper way to print an octal literal? For example, the following works for the hex digit `\x` but not for the octal `\0`:

```
printf("\x66 \0102\n");
```

> f 2

How can this be done?

Comment: David542, with `printf("\0102\n");`, what output did you want?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica `f B` so it should've been: `printf("\x66 \102\n")` -- I thought the leading `\0` was required for octal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Octal literal consists of 1 to 3 digits. 4-digit sequence like `\0102` is not supported. It seems this is treated as two characters: `\010` and `2`.

What you want may be `printf("\x66 \102\n");`. This will print `f B` if ASCII is used.

Quote from [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 6.4.4.4 Character constants:

> octal-escape-sequence:
> \ octal-digit
> \ octal-digit octal-digit
> \ octal-digit octal-digit octal-digit

> The octal digits that follow the backslash in an octal escape sequence are taken to be part
> of the construction of a single character for an integer character constant or of a single
> wide character for a wide character constant. The numerical value of the octal integer so
> formed specifies the value of the desired character or wide character.

Comment: I see, so within the format string no `0` is required to precede it.

Comment: @David542 This ruie is for any string literals and character constants, not only within the format strings.